# Storing a .html report with a data model

Tags: django

I am new to Django, and I am looking for the best approach to the following problem.

I have an application that is producing two reports. One is a JSON blob so I store it in psql with data model that uses JSONField.
The second report is a .html file.

The .html file will be generated multiple times a day so the first thing that came to mind was storing it in the db. 
I need to be able to pull the report as well so it can be displayed to the user in the UI.

I created a test data model using `TextField`:

```
class TestResultsHTML(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    report = models.TextField()
```

It makes it into the Db no problem, however when I attempt to retrieve it I can't seem to get the actual report:

```
In [3]: html_results =  TestResultsHTML.objects.get(id=4)

In [4]: html_results.name
Out[4]: 'b0f5c336-867a-44a3-a5ef-6297bf6042cf'

In [5]: html_results.report
Out[5]: "<_io.TextIOWrapper name='report.html' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>"
```

I was expected that .report would return the actual contents of the file. The file itself is 1800+ lines.

Is this a good approach or is this not the intended use of TextField?

Comment: Have you considered to store it into S3 or any other file storage?

Comment: That may be an option. Would it be better to store static pages in a cloud storage location? Right now this is all running on my local machine.

Comment: yes, for sure will be better if you store that in the cloud. It will be more reliable, more scalable and it is very easy to implement with the library Boto3 ( For AWS )
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html

Answer (score 0):

A TextField doesn't store the file, Django has a FileField for this (see [here)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#filefield). This saves the file to a certain location/folder and the object saved in the DB essentially stores that location which you can then access later. Something like this:

```
class TestResultsHTML(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    file_loc = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_location)
```

Then open the file at a later date with something like this:

```
with open(html_results.file_loc, 'w'):
```